# Algorithm for minimizing maximium product (candy and ballons)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, greedy, minimize, minimax

Hello I need help with the following problem:
we have `m` balloons and unlimited amount of candy.
Some kid wants us give him `ni` balloons in every `i` day (array `n`).
He also has a tax array `b` - which is tax `bi` on day `i`.
If we give the kid `ni` balloons on day `i` he is happy. If we give `k` balloons  `k < ni` on day `i`, we have to give the kid `(ni - k)*bi` candy.
We have to give the balloons in such way as to minimize the maximum amount of candy we give ON A GIVEN day.
 Example:
 we have `6` balloons `(m = 6)`

```
n = 1, 3, 3, 3, 2  
b = 4, 1, 5, 3, 7
```

we give balloons in following way

```
g = 0, 0, 2, 2, 2
```

In this way we have to give a maximum of  `(3 -2) * 5 = 5` on day 3 (indexing start from 1).

Please help me find an efficient solution to this problem. My current solution is greedy by removing one balloon at a time but is way too slow, because `m < 10^18`. `ai < 10^9 bi < 10^9 n < 10^5`

Comment: Maybe one-by-one removal is fine, but you have to have a sorted list of taxes per day, and update it after each removal, and always remove the balloon from the first item in the list. Also, if `m` is close to sum of `ni` then it could be more efficient to start from the opposite direction, and add taxes instead of removing them.

Comment: @גלעדברקן ai < 10^9 and bi < 10^9

Comment: @Dialecticus I do this but it gets Time limit exceeded because m < 10^18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to reach the minimum of the max daily tax with binary search.

Assume that the max daily tax would be `T_current` (half between 0 and the largest possible daily tax for the first iteration). Find the required number of balloons for each day so that they do not exceed `T_current`. Sum of all such balloons is `M_current`. If `M_current` is larger than input `M` then assume larger `T_current` for next iteration, and if it is smaller than assume smaller `T_current` for next iteration.

In each iteration you cut the search domain for `T` in half. You continue the binary search to find the `T_current` such that `M_current == M`. Once you have this `T_current` you also have the distribution of balloons.